Asking about CSI Extraction on Qualcomm ath79 (Atheros QCA956X) Target Architecture
I’m working on CSI (Channel State Information) extraction using the Atheros CSI Tool for my router, which runs on the Qualcomm Atheros QCA956X ver 1 rev 0 chipset and is based on the ath79/generic target architecture.
I’ve already installed OpenWrt on the router, but the available precompiled firmware I’ve found for CSI extraction seems outdated and incompatible with my architecture. I’m looking for new precompiled firmware that supports CSI extraction for this specific chipset and target.
Does anyone have access to a more recent precompiled firmware for ath79 architecture? Or is there a reliable source where I can download it?
Thanks for your help!
I tried using the Atheros CSI tool and I followed this web tutor but i got so much errors and wasn't able to cross compile the tool "https://github.com/xieyaxiongfly/Atheros_CSI_tool_OpenWRT_src/wiki/Install-OpenWRT-version-of-Atheros-CSI-tool" and this "https://wands.sg/research/wifi/AtherosCSI/document/Atheros-CSI-Tool-User-Guide(OpenWrt).pdf"
